# Invalid Free or corruption out

Tags: c, memory-management, free

I am new to C and totally lost by this problem. This is a homework assignment to implement something like the pagerank algorithm in C.

I am trying to record the links from other pages by way of a 2D pointer-pointer array. My program works just fine and happily calculates pagerank for large sets of links, however, whenever I try to free my links array I get an "invalid free" error.

example code:

```
struct webpage {
  char name[20];
  int links_out;
  struct webpage **links_in; //to hold pointers to pages.
  int index; //stores the position in the pre-sorted array
             // as I have to print it out in this order
};

static struct webpage *pages = NULL;
```

This is my data structure. After reading in some basic variables like the number of pages (npages) I then allocate memory

```
pages = (struct webpage *)calloc(npages, sizeof(struct webpage));
```

As I read in each webpage I allocate the internal 2d array links_in as follows

```
pages[counter].links_in = (struct webpage **)calloc(npages, sizeof(struct webpage *));
```

and then each page inside:

```
for(i =0; i< npages; ++i)
pages[counter].link_in[i] = (struct webpage *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct webpage));
```

I sort my array of webpages. Then read in the link information and binary search my array with bsearch to get a pointer to each desired page.

```
struct webpage *temp_in;
struct webpage *temp_out;

temp_in = bsearch(temp_str, pages, npages, sizeof(struct webpage), struct_cmp_by_name);
temp_out = bsearch(temp_str2, pages, npages, sizeof(struct webpage), struct_cmp_by_name);
```

Then I assign

```
temp_in->links_in[temp_out->index] = temp_out;
```

This all works great and I am able to access all the desired data to calculate pagerank. 
Once I am done I try to free the memory as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < npages; ++i){
  for(int k = 0; k < npages; ++k){
     if(pages[i].links_in[k] != NULL){
          free(pages[i].links_in[k]); //this line is causing the error
          pages[i].links_in[k] = NULL;
     }
  }
 free(pages[i].links_in);
}
```

The call to free inside the k loop throws an invalid free (or a double free corruption out) error the very first time it is called.

I have been over the code with gdb and things seem to be pointing to the right thing. gdb list that line as the point where the program breaks.

valgrind says much the same:

```
Invalid free() / delete / delete[]
at 0x4A05187: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:325)
by 0x4009C4: memory_dump (pagerank.c: 87)  // this is the line free(pages[i].links_in[k];
by 0x4013F2: seq_check_condition (pagerank.c:355)
by 0x40162F: main (pagerank.c:418)
```

At no point do I delete/free that (or any memory tbh) memory before that point.

thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: this does not answer your question, but have you sorted your array?

Comment: The array is sorted after all the pages are read in but before the links are defined

Comment: ok phoxis was correct. I shouldnt have allocated the memory for the inner array. I only needed the calloc for pages[i].links_in.

Comment: i would suggest a manual dry run to ensure that no memory leak is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not need to do the following

```
for(i =0; i< npages; ++i)
    pages[counter].link_in[i] = (struct webpage *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct webpage));
```

This is because for each page you allocate a new `webpage` pointer. The `pages[counter].link_in[i]` is used to hold the pointer to a `webpage` , ie. it should point to an already existing and allocated page. So you need to only assign the address of that `webpage` instance.

I think the problem is here:

Change your this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < npages; ++i){
  for(int k = 0; k < npages; ++k){
     if(pages[i].links_in[k] != NULL){
          free(pages[i].links_in[k]); //this line is causing the error
          pages[i].links_in[k] = NULL;
     }
  }
 free(pages[i].links_in);
}
```

To this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < npages; ++i){
   free (pages[i].links_in);
}
free (pages);
```

This is because the links the `pages[i].links_in[x]` holds are *pointers* to some `pages[j]`, and because a particular `pages[j]` address can occur in `pages[i].links_in[x]` for any number of `i`, so potentially the address of the `pages[j]` occurs in multiple places, which is attempted to be freed by your routine in the line `free(pages[i].links_in[k]);`.

Please let us know if this helps.

Comment: IF I change my code as per the second part of your answer the error disappears, but the memory allocated for link[k] is lost. I will try making the first change you suggested.

Comment: there should be no memory leak, provided you also follow the first part of my answer, by not allocating the `webpage` structures. This is because you are using the `link_in` to *point* to an existing memory location, and for that you do not need to allocate a new copy of memory. Instead, by doing the `calloc` (which i highlighted in my answer) will result in memory leak. I would suggest a further research on your code.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is this is the problem:

```
temp_in->links_in[temp_out->index] = temp_out;
```

It seems you've already allocated memory for all your 'links_in' pointers - then you're changing that pointer to point to another bit of memory you've allocated.

Maybe you want something like:

```
memcpy(temp_in->links_in[temp_out->index], temp_out, sizeof(struct webpage));
```

...or a bit of a redesign?

Comment: ok that was odd. I made that change and I got a seg-fault. sizeof both variables is well within the size of struct webpage.

Comment: copying the entire webpage structure is not a good idea i think, instead the pointer to that page would be better.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `pages[i].links_in[k]` should be `pages[i].link_in[k]`.